# Spring-Integration: Logging: Getting the bean name from within a AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice

Tags: xml, spring, logging, spring-integration, declarative

With `Spring-Integration 6.0.0` I'm using `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice` to log calls to `http:outbound-gateway` implicitly (both the outgoing request message headers and payload and the incoming response message headers and payload).

But I'm a bit stuck on retrieving the name of the `http:outbound-gateway` bean itself from within the `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice`.

The `doInvoke()` method receives an argument that contain the name of the `http:outbound-gateway` beans, unfortunately within a private class.

```java
@Override
protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) {
    ...
    final String outboundGatewayName = ((AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.AdvisedRequestHandler) target).getAdvisedHandler().getBeanName();
    ...
}
```

The `target` argument is a private subclass `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.AdvisedRequestHandler` which does contain the method `getAdvisedHandler()` which returns the `http:outbound-gateway` bean and allows retrieving the bean name with `getBeanName()`: however, since this subclass is `private`, I can't do this without some special reflection work.

Is there a non-private way of retrieving the name of the target bean from the `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice`?  I would think that this would be important for logging.

Comment: Looks like this will do it: using the public interface ```RequestHandler``` :

```final String outboundGatewayName = ((AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.RequestHandler) target).getAdvisedHandler().getBeanName();```

Comment: So, this is an answer: just post it and accept yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: OK, was quite happy for someone else to answer.  Thanks for the encouragement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this will do it: using the public interface RequestHandler :

```java
    final String outboundGatewayName = 
        ((AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.RequestHandler) target)
            .getAdvisedHandler()
            .getBeanName();
```